# mysql and case sensitivity real confusing

Tags: mysql

Windows OS - phpMyAdmin

```
select auth, COUNT(*) AS count from posts where auth = 1;
```

gives an info:

```
Your SQL query has been executed successfully
```

but:

```
select auth, count(*) AS count from posts where auth = 1;
```

gives the following:

```
Showing rows 0 - 0 (1 total, Query took 0.0070 seconds.
```

[here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) I found a real confusing story about MySql and case sensitivity.

Is there any common best practice about writing queries, regarding lower or upper case, or I must learn all rules separatelly, for each OS?

Comment: I don't see any difference when I execute it myself.

Comment: You say `case sensitivity`, but what field is string there? also you should include group by.

Comment: @juergend, if there is no difference, in second case I also expect an info like - 'Your SQL query has been executed successfully'

Comment: Can you provide some testing. I cant reproduce this. `COUNT()` and `count()` are the same http://rextester.com/KFIEVE30269

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, could you try in phpMyAdmin? Why there is no `Your SQL query has been executed successfully` in second case?

Comment: No I dont have it. But then the problem is with phpMyAdmin no with mySql

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, so if you're sure, it could be an answer.

Comment: Well that is why I provide the link with a test. I couldnt reproduce it there. You can try yourself.

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
 select auth, count(*) AS count 
 from posts 
 where auth = 1
 group by auth
 ;
```

Comment: it's ok but why I'm not required this in the first case?

Comment: As I say. I cant reproduce that behaviour

Comment: do you have phpMyAdmin?